# Notes Formula Language Date Difference

Tags: database, view, formula, lotus-notes

I want to build a view only containing the most recent documents (newer than 2 months). I am using this select formular:

```
SELECT  @IsAvailable($Conflict) and docForm="ServiceOrders" and (@Today-PosDesValidFrom)<5259600
```

Where the 5259600 are the 2 Months in seconds because I read that the - Operator returns the timespan in seconds. 
I do not have any results in my view.

Answer (score 2):

*Never* use @Today or @Now in view selection formulas. The view index will then never be up-to-date, hence the update task will run constantly to refresh the index. This will affect performance negatively.

What you should do is have a daily (or in your case probably nightly) agent that will flag the documents to display in the view.
To make the agent as fast as possible, process a view where you are displaying the date in one of the columns.

The absolutely fastest would be like this:

1. Create a hidden view called `(LookupServiceOrdersByValidDate)`.
2. The first column will contain the field name `PosDesValidFrom` (I will assume it is a date field, otherwise you need to convert it to date), and be sorted descending. Go to the fourth tab in the infobox for the column and make sure you have it set to Date/Time.
   [image: column properties illustrating what was described]
3. Create a second column where you display the text field `DisplayIn2MonthView`. Sort descending as well.
4. Save the view.

You now have a view you can loop through using an agent. Since it is sorted descending with the newest at the top, as soon as you reach a date more than 2 months back, you can stop the agent and be done.

The script would look something like this:

```
Dim session as New NotesSession
Dim db as NotesDatabase
Dim view as NotesView
Dim col as NotesViewEntryCollection
Dim entry as NotesViewEntry
Dim doc as NotesDocument
Dim validDate as NotesDateTime
Dim cutoffDate As NotesDateTime

' Get current date and time and go back 2 months
Set cutoffDate = New NotesDateTime(Now())
Call cutoffDate.AdjustMonth(-2)
' Drill down to view
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set view = db.GetView("(LookupServiceOrdersByValidDate)")
' Create a collection of all entries in the view and loop through them
Set col = view.AllEntries
Set entry = col.GetFirstEntry()
Do Until entry is Nothing
    ' Get value in first column in view and use it to create new DateTime object
    validDate = New NotesDateTime(entry.ColumnValues(0))
    ' Check if we are within the 2 month cutoff date
    If Cdat(validDate.dateOnly)>=Cdat(cutoffDate) Then
        ' Get document and set flag to display
        Set doc = entry.Document
        Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("DisplayIn2MonthView","Yes")
        Call doc.Save(True,False)
    Else
        ' We are beyond the cutoff date, but we need to clear old flags.
        ' Read the value in the second column and see if it is "Yes"
        If entry.ColumnValues(1)="Yes" Then
            Set doc = entry.Document
            Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("DisplayIn2MonthView","")
            Call doc.Save(True,False)
        Else
            ' Since all "Yes" values should be at the top, if we
            ' get here there should be no more flagged documents.
            Exit Do
        End If
    End If
    Set entry = col.GetNextEntry(entry)
Loop
Print "All done."
```

Finally, modify the view to display the documents. You should probably use the `Form` field, not `docForm`. Set the selection formula to
`SELECT !@IsAvailable($Conflict) AND Form="ServiceOrders" AND DisplayIn2MonthView="Yes"`
The view should now only contain the ServiceOrder documents with a ValidDate within the last 2 months.
If you really want only replication/save conflicts in the view, make sure the view is set to *not* display response documents in a hierarchy (uncheck the box):
[image: view properties illustrating what was described]

Comment: That is a very intelligent idea, unfortunate thing is that I do not have the permission to create new fields in the forms.

Comment: For some reason I am getting a type mismatch on cutoffDate here: CDat(validDate.dateOnly)>=CDat(cutoffDate)

Comment: @exasswede This solution kind of works for me but the problem is that a new order will not appear visible until the agent runs over the view.

Comment: Another alternative would be to create a NotesDocumentCollection using the db.search() method, and then use the .stampAll() method on the DC.

Comment: @curnir: Regarding the type mismatch, what does the debugger say? I wrote that code directly here in my response, so it is untested. Which exact line did you get the error on?  
If you want new documents to show up immediatly, just reverse the logic. Set the flag to "No" and filter out any documents with that value instead of including the ones with "Yes".  
And you actually don't need to create new fields on the forms, by using doc.ReplaceItemValue() you create the field with the data directly in the document. This is the beauty of a schema-less NoSQL database like Domino.

Comment: @Karl-HenryMartinsson it's been about a decade since I've done anything with Notes/Domino but I thought there was a way to limit the frequency of the view updates?